# What does bootstrap function do in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm very new to frontend frameworks and I am learning Angular 2. In the tutorial, it tells you to include the line `bootstrap(AppComponent)`.   What does this bootstrap function do?  Is it simply what starts the app?  I'm guessing it has nothing to do with the [twitter-bootstrap](/questions/tagged/twitter-bootstrap) UI framework.

Comment: Yes.  Bootstrapping is what starts the app - by loading the specific module you tell angular to bootstrap.

Answer (score 5):

From [the docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/bootstrap-function.html):

> You instantiate an Angular application by explicitly specifying a component to use as the root component for your application via the bootstrap() method.

So yes, it just starts the application.

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 4):

`bootstrap()` initializes an Angular application by executing (beside others)

- creating the Angular zone,
- creating the root injector and
- executing factories provided by `APP_INITIALIZER`
- instantiating and adding the root component.

Answer (score 2):

`bootstrap` is the function which tells `Angular2` system to render component over page as main component.

Also defines entity point of your application, by specifying root of your application.

```
//basically array will have dependencies of shared component which will instantiate only once.
bootstrap(MyComponent, [SharedService, OtherComponent, ROUTING_DIRECTIVES]);
```

But yes you should have mention that component selector over `index.html` page like

```
<my-component></my-component>
```

If you compare this with Angular 1, you will find `ng-app` directive which takes `angular.module` name as an input like `ng-app="myApp"` and make available those module component for that application **OR** `angular.bootstrap` function to kick off application over the page.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `bootstrap()` in angular2 tell us the Entry point for the app very similer to `ng-app` in angular 1.x, it creates angular zone for the whole app,In Angular 1.x we could use the `ng-app` Directive, and give it a value such as `ng-app="myApp"`, or use the angular.bootstrap method which allows for asynchronous bootstrapping.

The place we need to fetch the bootstrap method is angular2/platform/browser

```
  import {bootstrap} from 'angular2/platform/browser';
  ... Some Code stuff

  bootstrap(AppComponent, [Common providers, or Global services, varibale etc]);
```

also we can inject GlobalServices, variables which we are going to use in the whole app at the time of bootstraping our app,
  by doing so we dont nees to imports those again and again in our components.

Answer (score 0):

And now in Angular5:

- [The *bootstrap* array](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#bootstrap-array)

> You launch the application by [*bootstrapping*](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#main) the root `AppModule`. Among other things, the bootstrapping process creates the component(s) listed in the `bootstrap` array and inserts each one into the browser DOM.

Further reading:

- [Bootstrap in *main.ts*](https://angular.io/guide/bootstrapping#main)